# Renaming of cross references not happening if the cross references are cached

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

I have a sample model i am using as below

```
grammar org.xtext.example.testdsl.TestDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate testDsl "http://www.xtext.com/test/example/TestDsl"

Model:
prog+=Program*;

Program: g=Greeting  de+=DataEntry* s+=Statement*;
Greeting: 'Hello' t=ProgPara '!';
ProgPara: 'PROGRAM'  pname=Progname ';';
Progname : name=ID;

DataEntry:  a=INT (v=Varname| in=Indexname) ';';   
Varname : name = ID;

Statement: c=CopyStmt ';';
CopyStmt: 'COPY' 'TO' qname=[IndexVarname|ID] ;
IndexVarname : (Indexname|Varname);   
Indexname : '(' name = ID ')';

Named:Progname|Indexname|Varname;
```

I have added caching support for Scoping like in the code below:

```
class TestDslScopeProvider extends AbstractTestDslScopeProvider {
@Inject
IResourceScopeCache cache;

override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof CopyStmt) {
        if (reference.featureID == TestDslPackage.COPY_STMT__QNAME) {
            val candidates = cache.get(
                "COPY_STMT__QNAME_scope",
                reference.eResource,
                [|findQNameCandidates(context, reference)]
            );
            return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
        }   
        }
        return super.getScope(context, reference);      
  }

  def findQNameCandidates(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context);
    val candidates1 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, IndexVarname);
    return candidates1;
  }
}
```

Now i have a sample test case as below:

```
Hello PROGRAM test;!
1 test1;
2 (test4);
3 test3;

COPY TO test4;
COPY TO test4;
```

When i try to rename test4 using the Rename Element, only the variable in the definition is getting renamed. The references are not getting renamed. Without caching it works fine, but when caching is done, i hit this issue. What am i missing here?

Thanks,
Anitha

Comment: which refactoring do you use? the old or the new one?

Comment: and the problem might be that the scope is not invalidated on the rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do cache wrong

```
reference.eResource
```

you need to use the context resource as cache not the metamodels

```
context.eResource,
```

Comment: Thanks once again Christian. Great help.